# android recyclerView horizontal and vertical spacing

Tags: android

Hi all I am very new to android and I am having a problem with recyclerview. I am trying to add space between image views in a recyclerview but I am not successful.

What I want

[image]

What is happening

[image]

Below  are my implementations
***ItemOffsetDecoration.java***

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int itemOffset;

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
        itemOffset = itemOffset;
    }

    public ItemOffsetDecoration(@NonNull Context context, @DimenRes int itemOffsetId) {
        this(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(itemOffsetId));
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.set(itemOffset, itemOffset, itemOffset, itemOffset);
    }
}
```

***shopping.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shopping_bg"
    tools:context=".activities.HomepageActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/shoppingRV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/grid_horizontal_spacing"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***Shopping.java***

```
public class Shopping extends Fragment implements InstaPukkeiRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    InstaPukkeiRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_shopping, container, false);
        processRV(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void processRV(View layout) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.shoppingRV);
        int noOfColumns = 3;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), noOfColumns));
        adapter = new InstaPukkeiRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), LogoIds.SHOPPING_SITE_LOGOS);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(getContext(), R.dimen.grid_horizontal_spacing));
    }
}
```

Please help me here. Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***
item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share ur item layout

Comment: In your item layout file `tab_shopping.xml` try to set some margin attribute to the root layout

Comment: Try to use Linear layouy with horizontal orientation, instead Relative

Comment: @ShubhamJain I have added the item layout in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:marginLeft="18dp"
    android:marginRight="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Change your item layout with this one in your item's XML. You make the parent(LinearLayout) height match parent that's why you are getting vertical full screen space

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrap_content` in RecyclerView and also in row layout.And also add margins

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/shoppingRV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/grid_horizontal_spacing"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm you can add margin to your `image view` or use dimen to set height and width something like this

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_130"
android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_120"
```

or

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_15"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Recycleview set layout height to wrap_content