# Android app crashes with out of memory

Tags: android

I am developing an App with 4 tabs.

1. Tab 1: Expandable `listview` with 20 groups
2. Tab 2: Expandable `listview` with 30 groups
3. Tab 3: `Gridview` with 22 items (3 column per row)
   [scrollable] 
   4.Tab 4: Grid view with 24 items (3 column per row)
   [scrollable]

**My `Gridview` adapter implementation is below:(Same is used for both tab 3 and 4)**

```
public class LogoImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> logoIds;
    public LogoImageAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> logoIds) {
        this.context = context;
        this.logoIds = logoIds;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return logoIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return logoIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return logoIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        } else {
            gridView = convertView;
        }
        /*TextView title = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.siteNameTV);
            title.setText("Title_" + position);*/
        ImageView logoImage = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
        logoImage.setImageResource(logoIds.get(position));
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

Thing is that the app consumes almost 100 MB memory and frequently crashes.
I think the app crashing is due to my gridview implementation. Where I am making a mistake?

[image]

***EDIT:
Logcat:***

```
10-05 15:06:55.458 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Classified{3fc90a #0 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:06:57.907 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tourism{33f7512 #2 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:06:59.856 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Shopping{6a52599 #3 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:3} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:07:02.252 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Travel{26da709 #4 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:4} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:07:02.387 32557-32568/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 102MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:07.410 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tourism{33f7512 #2 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:07:08.494 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:08.501 32557-32568/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 103MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:08.502 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 8.292ms for cause Alloc
10-05 15:07:08.502 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:11.500 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tourism{33f7512 #2 id=0x7f0c006d android:switcher:2131492973:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
10-05 15:07:12.775 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:12.775 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:12.802 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 481(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(3MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/96MB, paused 465us total 26.676ms
10-05 15:07:12.906 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:12.906 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:12.917 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 103MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:12.917 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 840(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(7MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 87MB/96MB, paused 599us total 10.801ms
10-05 15:07:14.432 32557-32564/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-05 15:07:15.214 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.214 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.225 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 250(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 803us total 10.646ms
10-05 15:07:15.226 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.237 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 102MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.238 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 727(59KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(6MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 86MB/96MB, paused 467us total 11.147ms
10-05 15:07:15.318 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.318 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.323 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.331 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.331 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 592(58KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 441us total 7.585ms
10-05 15:07:15.331 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.346 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.347 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 408us total 14.839ms
10-05 15:07:15.347 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3MB allocation
10-05 15:07:15.347 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.366 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.366 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 459us total 18.639ms
10-05 15:07:15.366 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2923072 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"
10-05 15:07:15.376 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.376 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.381 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.390 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.390 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 430us total 8.601ms
10-05 15:07:15.390 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.405 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.406 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 435us total 14.874ms
10-05 15:07:15.406 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3MB allocation
10-05 15:07:15.406 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-05 15:07:15.422 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 109MB to 96MB
10-05 15:07:15.422 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 420us total 15.551ms
10-05 15:07:15.422 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2916528 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"
10-05 15:07:15.423 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
10-05 15:07:15.423 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-05 15:07:15.453 32557-32557/pmp.com.instapukkei E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: pmp.com.instapukkei, PID: 32557
                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2916528 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                                         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2638)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2543)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimationDrawable.java:330)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:300)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2633)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2543)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3957)
                                                                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:155)
                                                                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                         at pmp.com.instapukkei.tabs.Tourism.onCreateView(Tourism.java:31)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                        at com.andr
```

Comment: share your logcat

Comment: use less size images in app

Comment: You are using big images. Try increasing the heap size. And possibly using less and smaller images.

Comment: @ysl I have added the logcat.

Comment: @sushildlh I have total 50 + plus images which all total accounts 3.99MB

Comment: image size should be less than 100kb or less per image

Comment: Are you saying adding size of all the drawables should be less or equal 100kb? or one image should be less or equal 100kb? @sushildlh

Comment: yeah try to do with 50kb to 80kb not more. And remeber for the future projects also

Comment: So you mean adding size of all the drawables should be less or equal 100kb. One question does scrolling causes redrawing of the gridview which is causing the issue?

Comment: @MrG dude, just use Glide as i described in my answer, leave your images as it is

Answer (score 2):

Convert your Images in WEbp format

[Click Here for WEbp Format](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html)

add to your Menifest This is Temporary Solution

```
<application
   ........................
   android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: I will try WEBP and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Optimize your images (which in your `logoIds` list) with one of available solutions, such as

[This](https://tinypng.com/) or just reExport in right way from your PhotoShop(or whatever you use).

And another AND RIGHT way is to generate diffrent icons for diffrent dpi([see tools](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit))

> And i strongly recommend you to use Glide or Picasso to load images inside lists, cause they have build-in caching which is good for recycled views

**UPD:** sample of use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#glide) to load resources

```
Glide.with(convertView.getContext())
.load(R.id.resource_id)
.into(imageView);
```

And use [**ViewHolder** pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview) in your adapter, to avoid rebinding views on recycling (`gridView.findViewById(R.id.logoImageView)`)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Inside application tag.

```
<application
    ....
       android:largeHeap="true">
```

check [this details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: @MrG But note, that this solution(i mean `largeHeap="true"`) is only makes your app to have a bit large RAM memory space, but it's not solution for your problem

Comment: @AmitVaghela while this may work, allocating too much RAM over a short period of time is denied by the system. Even with largeHeap, allocating a lot of images over a too short period of time will throw an OOME. And even largeHeap has its limitations. The best way to solve the OOME is to use largeHeap **in combination with** either a library (like picasso) or resizing the images.

Comment: @AmitVaghela I downvoted because the majority of the answer is in the target link. Links can die

Comment: @Zoe hey man, this is a protected question it can not be deleted that easily and plus it is a stackoverflow link. all answer has descriptions.

Comment: @AmitVaghela the same rules apply. Just because it's on SO doesn't mean it's except from the link rules

Comment: @AmitVaghela can you comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569833/android-recyclerview-horizontal-and-vertical-spacing